# What should I do If a bountied question is a duplicate of another

Tags: discussion

I came across a question that has a bounty on it.  After reading the question, I felt that it might be 85-90% similar to an answer to another question that I answered.  I also know that we are not supposed to add the same answer to two different questions.  So if I want to answer the bountied question, what should I do?

What I did on one question, is leave a comment, that tells the user offering the bounty, that this answer might be the one they are looking for.  So is that enough to get the bounty if that really was the right answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're *sure* the question is a duplicate, custom flag the question asking a moderator to refund the bounty and close the question. If the bountier needs more than the answers to the master question he can add a bounty to *that* question.

Answer (score 2):

Seth [covered](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6666/1992) basically all I was going to say.

I'll just add, the person giving the bounty will also get a nice badge (or two(?)) for adding a bounty to another person's question if it is their first time.